# Matthew Daly Django Tutorial Test Fail

Tags: django, postgresql

I am using `postgres` instead of `mySQL` for a django install.  However, during a test with postgres I am getting an error I cannot explain; the error does not exist if I change back to mySQL.

```
def test_edit_post(self):
    # Create the post
    post = Post()
    post.title = 'My first post'
    post.text = 'This is my first blog post'
    post.pub_date = timezone.now()
    post.save()

    # Log in
    self.client.login(username='FredFlintstone', password='Pebbles')

    # Edit the post
    response = self.client.post('/admin/blogengine/post/1/', {
        'title': 'My second post',
        'text': 'This is my second blog post',
        'pub_date_0': '2013-08-08',
        'pub_date_1': '22:00:04'
    },
    follow=True
    )
    self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)
```

If I use postgres I get a status_code 404, but it works with `mySQL`.

I suspected I didn't have postgres setup correctly but this works:

```
    def test_create_post(self):
    # Log in
    self.client.login(username='FredFlintstone', password='Pebbles')

    # Check add response code
    response = self.client.get('/admin/blogengine/post/add/')
    self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)

    # Create new post
    response = self.client.post('/admin/blogengine/post/add/', {
        'title': 'My first post',
        'text': 'This is my first post',
        'pub_date_0': '2013-12-28',
        'pub_date_1': '22:00:04'
    },
    follow=True
    )
    self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)
```

I am new to django and development in general.  Any help you can provide will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This issue cropped up later on when I did the final part of the tutorial, where we upgraded to Django 1.7.

> There are two main issues here. The first is that when we try to edit or delete an existing item, or refer to it when creating something else, we can no longer rely on the number representing the primary key being set to 1. So we need to specifically obtain this, rather than hard-coding it to 1. Therefore, whenever we pass through a number to represent an item (with the exception of the site, but including tags, categories and posts), we need to instead fetch its primary key and return it. So, above where we try to delete a post, we replace 1 with str(post.pk). This will solve a lot of the problems.

In other words, you need to obtain the post's primary key programmatically, rather than hard-coding it in the test.

The solution is at http://matthewdaly.co.uk/blog/2014/09/28/django-blog-tutorial-the-next-generation-part-9/, but I have reproduced it below:

```
def test_edit_post(self):
    # Create the post
    post = PostFactory()

    # Create the category
    category = CategoryFactory()

    # Create the tag
    tag = TagFactory()
    post.tags.add(tag)

    # Log in
    self.client.login(username='bobsmith', password="password")

    # Edit the post
    response = self.client.post('/admin/blogengine/post/' + str(post.pk) + '/', {
        'title': 'My second post',
        'text': 'This is my second blog post',
        'pub_date_0': '2013-12-28',
        'pub_date_1': '22:00:04',
        'slug': 'my-second-post',
        'site': '1',
        'category': str(category.pk),
        'tags': str(tag.pk)
    },
    follow=True
    )
    self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)

    # Check changed successfully
    self.assertTrue('changed successfully' in response.content)

    # Check post amended
    all_posts = Post.objects.all()
    self.assertEquals(len(all_posts), 1)
    only_post = all_posts[0]
    self.assertEquals(only_post.title, 'My second post')
    self.assertEquals(only_post.text, 'This is my second blog post')
```

Hope that helps!